# Move from login page to dashboard after successful login in react js

Tags: reactjs

using React js I am trying to move from login page to dashboard page but i am not getting the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

Find an example for authorization flows with react-router-dom here:

https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/tree/main/examples/auth

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `router`? If yes, you can use `useNavigate` in `react-router-dom` to navigate to another path when you've done login

Ex:

```
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom'
...

export default function App(){
   const navaigate = useNavigate()

   const handleLogin = () => {  
      //do something
      ...
      navigate('/dashboard') //or whatever path you wish
   }

   return (
       ....
   )
}
```

Note: It is only working if your React App using Router

Answer (score 0):

Please refer https://github.com/VickyDhanwani/ReactJS-App/blob/main/src/App.js if you are not using react router. Navigation is based on state and update in state changes the view after validation.